# Azure Function test with azure DevOps pipelines

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have an **Azure function** Project and I want to use the **Azure DevOps** `pipelines` tests and also running my own tests

[project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0Msu.png)

I do not know how to integrate my test project into the repository

[project git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrgAc.png)

and how to use it the azure DevOps `pipelines`

Thank you

Comment: Could you please give some example of things you have tried? Generally, searching for this on a search engine would result in better answers than could be provided by StackOverflow, as this is a specific Q+A site not for general programming questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears your unit test project isn't pushed to your Git repo. The project files don't show any padlock (see image 1), and the files aren't in the repo (see image 2).

Commit and push the files and try again.

**Edit**
Git works on a folder, not on a Visual Studio solution or project. This means you can add *any file* under the folder where you cloned the Git repo.

To add the files to your Git repo from Visual Studio, please see [Save work with commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/commits?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio)

In short:
- Go to Team Explorer - Changes
- Stage the changes you want to commit
- Commit the changed files
- Sync with the repo

Comment: How to add the two since they are two separate projects? (image 1)